# What is an academic and formal way to define variables?

Tags: physics, science

I'm currently writing my IB Extended Essay in physics. I wonder how I can define variables in a formal way. I originally used a triple bar (e.g. "F≡buoyant force"). However, I'm not sure if this is formal or even correct. What is an academic and formal way to define variables?

Comment: What have you seen in other papers in your field? Follow that.

Comment: Several standard methods used in mathematics [are given here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/5166/264), but I have no idea which would be well known, somewhat known, or entirely unknown in your field. If you feel that you **have** to have such a symbol, then I suggest you simply pick the version that seems most intuitive to you and is easy to "type" using your text software program, and define the symbol in a footnote the first time you use it. In handouts/notes for students, I have usually used an = sign with "def" just over the top of it (seemed most likely to be understood from context).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The academic way to define variables is to simply describe them in the text. For instance,

> *F = ma*,
>   where *F* is the force acting on the point mass *m* and *a* is the acceleration.

In fact, we want scientific texts to be readable, and not overburdened with unnecessary and obscure notations. Symbols have their role, but don't overuse them. Even more, a symbol like the triple bar has different *technical* meanings in different disciplines and using it in that way may just generate confusion.

Answer (score 2):

In most contexts involving applied mathematics, the triple bar symbol will be recognisable as stipulating a definition, but it would only be used if you are defining one variable in terms of others.  If you are merely giving the textual meaning of the variable, it is better just to write that out in ordinary prose, just as [Massimo](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/20058/o) shows in his answer.  However, if you want to distinguish a definitional equation from an equation arising as a logical consequence of other premises, it is perfectly acceptable to use the triple-bar sign for a definition.